# How to install Linux subsystem(ubuntu) from CLI on Windows 10

Tags: windows

Enable developer mode in GUI settings is failed, so is there a way to install Linux subsystem from CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Run following command in PowerShell will install Linux on Windows 10

```
PS C:\> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
```